# Is there a decent flat-rate online backup solution for Linux machines?

Tags: linux, backup

Has anyone found a Mozy (or Backblaze) like solution for backing up Linux boxes?  I'm hoping for something with a flat-rate fee for a backup plan ideally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Crashplan](http://www3.crashplan.com/consumer) : 1 year plan is $4.50 a month, unlimited.
3 year plan is $3.50 a month.

Local backup, or backup to a friend is free.

Comment: Thats the only proper cross-platform, flat-rate service that's been linked: good find!

Comment: FYI it is Java based. Not exactly light weight.

Comment: One thing to note about Crashplan is that the flat-rate plan is only for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using [Tarsnap](http://www.tarsnap.com/) it's a small venture by the head of the freebsd security chief. [Colin Percival](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/2/967/826). A very well respected man in his field. It uses amazon S3 in the background and leverages transfering and storing changes in files instead of the entire set. Everything gets encrypted to your own key (so no leveraging your storage with anyone else) and you only pay for what you use. The site is still in "beta" but the product works as described and has quite a few rounds of testing. Solid stuff.

> Tarsnap is an online encrypted snapshotted backup service, currently undergoing public paid beta testing.

At the very least read a few of his blog posts about tarsnap, very enlightening discoveries in there.

Comment: Just to note this does somewhat similar things to what jungle disk and a few others do but adds solid encryption and diffed snapshots on top of it. Colin can explain it better then I could.

Answer (score 5):

I use Jungle Disk with the CloudFiles option (JD has a Linux version).  They charge 15 cents/month storage and NO TRAFFIC FEES.

Answer (score 5):

[Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) works really well on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows. It works much better than Mozy for me. Upto 2 GiB it is free. For $99 a year you get 50 GiB of storage.

Comment: I use Dropbox myself.  Though it's designed as a tool to sync files between computers, I mostly use it for online backup and online access to files.  Has Windows and Linux support.  Great tool.

Answer (score 2):

We've been using JungleDisk on Ubuntu to back up (and keep synchronized) over 4 million files.  We use rdiff-backup and it works extremely well.

We're backing up about 900 gigabytes right now and still growing...

I think you'll find that JungleDisk (or any other Amazon S3 client) works very well.

The nice thing about JungledDisk is they have a Widows, Linux, and Mac client.

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution is to buy two simple NAS devices with a trusted friend of yours, like the WD MyBook World edition. You can easily get ssh access on those devices.

Place one NAS with you and one NAS with him. Costs are equally shared and you can upload everything you want to your own NAS.

For $150 you get 1GB of storage including the embedded computer - Amazon etc is way more expensive.

Comment: You know, I think thats the most inovative idea thats been suggested.  Not rock-solid but reasonable value and solves the off-site problem as well.  Good call!

Comment: Did you mean 1TB of storage?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [rsync.net](http://www.rsync.net/) for a few years without any problems. It doesn't have the fancy UI etc. of the services you mention but on the plus side it uses open standards so you can use a wide number of tools with it. (e.g. rsync, scp, sftp, ftp, rdiff-backup, Unison, duplicity)

Answer (score 0):

I just found [SpiderOak](http://spideroak.com/), which is fully cross platform (Mac, Win, Linux) and as a bonus is a big OSS supporter, having open sourced several of the libraries they developed internally.  They're not flat-rate, but rather 'stepped' - $10/100GB/mo or $100/100GB/yr, and no bandwidth fees.  I may move my backups there from S3 (which I suspect they use on the backend, but they get bulk discount rates that I don't as an individual).

Comment: I tried using SpiderOak for backups a couple of years back and it was absolutely terrible - syncs did not complete, many files were not backed up, and restores also failed to work completely.  It's very memory intensive as well.

Answer (score 0):

We just use rsync and a hosted linux VPS with a bunch of storage. It's a flat rate, we can't even come close to the bandwidth allotment, it's incremental, it's easy to cron, and it's simple and has been well-supported since the dialup days.

Answer (score 0):

I will second the recommendation for rsync.net.

I chose their swiss location for my account and use plain old rsync-over-ssh to back up my home dir, etc., out of cron.

Since they use stock OpenSSH on their end, I can use the entire suite of sshFS tools to mount the remote filesystem as well, which is nice.

Comment: Your seconding the recommendation would be more visible if you voted for it then added a comment. As it is the post are out of order and both towards the bottom with no votes.